# Javascript ShoppingCart

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

1. Create a ShoppingCart class with the following attributes

a.    items(variable): a member variable for collection of cart item, item name as key, item quantity as value

b.    deliveryFee(variable): the variable that hold the value of delivery fee which is calculated based on the number of item in the collection of item (50 Naira per cart Item)

c.    netTotal(variable): total amount of item in the cart

d.    grossTotal(variable): total amount of everything, price of item and delivery fee

e.    calculateDeliveryFee: function=>returns calculated delivery fee based on items

f.    addItem(name, quantity, price): function=add item to the shopping cart

g.    removeItem(name, quantity, price): function=>remove item from shopping cart

h.    checkout(paid_amount): function=>if paid_amount is smaller than the amount to be paid return “Insufficient fund” else clear the cart and return the balance

Comment: Please refer this document :https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Have you tried something?